# Raspberry Pi - Login Messages?

Tags: authentication, raspberry-pi, message

When I log in on my Raspberry Pi I get this login message:

```
Linux raspberrypi 3.10.25+ #622 PREEMPT Fri Jan 3 18:41:00 GMT 2014 armv6l
No mail.
Last login: Fri Apr 25 07:21:48 2014 from -

   Uptime.........: 0 days, 0h:57m
   Memory Usage...: Total: 437 Used: 163 Free: 273 Cached: 410 Swap: 0
   Load Averages..: 0.16, 0.06, 0.11
   Temperature....: 51.4°C
   Disk Usage.....: 2.1GB (15%) of 15GB, 4MB in /home/pi
   USB Usage......: 972MB of 7.5GB
   Processes......: Total: 67 User: 5
   SSH Logins.....: Currently 1 user(s) logged in.
   IP Address.....: -

No mail for pi
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

To display the Uptime and so on I use a script which is executed in /etc/profile, but where is the command located to display the second line with "No mail."? I want to remove this one but I can't find any file where the command could be located. It's neither ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile and I can't find anything in /etc/profile. /etc/motd is empty as well.
Does anyone know another file I could look up?
Uninstalling mailutils didn't help as well tho

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?

You should have something like this:

```
# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login
session    optional    pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]
```

Commenting this last line should remove the message concerning your mailbox.